# Creating complex validations using microsoft Enterprise library validation block

Tags: .net, validation, enterprise-library

I want to implement the following type of validations using Validation block.
I am using EntLib 5.0 and in SQL Server database I am storing the validation rules.
How to create the following validations using EntLib 5.0 Designer tool.

```
If(PaymentType == 'CreditCard')
{
     if(BilledAmount<100)
     {
         ErrorMsg = "Bill amount should greater than or equal to 100";
     }
     else if (BillAmount + TaxAmount > CreditCardMaxLimit)
     {
         ErrorMsg= "Credit card Max Amount limit is " + CreditCardMAxLimit;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to be able to use the designer, because that only works with pre-built validation options (Required, max length, etc).  You're using custom logic.

I would recommend using Self Validation.  Mark your object with the [HasSelfValidation] attribute and then mark your validation method with the [SelfValidation] attribute.  See here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/256355/Microsoft-Enterprise-Library-5-0-Introduction-to-V